# Is there a way to pop back to previous navigation controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a base nav controller which has a tab bar controller nested inside. inside that tab bar controller is another nav controller nested in it. If I'm in the child nav controller I can pop to root view in one of the views but it only takes me to the root view of the CHILD nav controller. Is there a way to pop back to the first nav controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are **using storyboard** then you can **use Unwind segue approach** which always works for me

[image]

Just Control + drag from "Pop to Main Screen" UIButton to Exit (green button at bottom  of scene) select unwind method declared in first screen with title "Main" e.g.

```
-(IBAction)customUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Unwind successful");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but my unbutton is created programmatically, so I can't drag from it in storyboard.

Comment: Just went ahead and created UIButton in Storyboard and used this approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
You can pop to root view from the child nav controller by

```
 UITabBarController *tc = (UITabBarController *)self.navigationController.parentViewController;
[tc.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but nothing is happening when this code executes.